# When I git stash and then git stash pop my changes are always unstaged

Tags: git

If I have some staged files and some unstaged files and I need to stash them temporarily I run:

```
git stash
```

Then when I want them back later I do:

```
git stash pop
```

However, the files are now *all* unstaged, even if they were staged previously before stashing. Is there any way to pop a stash such that it remembers which files are staged and unstaged and restores them to the exact state they were in before you stashed them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Sam answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291445/1256452), you want to use the `--index` option.  It's helpful to understand what is going on internally though.

When you *make* a stash—with `git stash save`, or the newer verb, `git stash push`<sup>1</sup>—Git actually writes out two commits.  This is because the commit is Git's essential unit of storage.<sup>2</sup>  The reason there are *two* of them is that one of them stores what is in Git's *index*, and the other stores what is in your *work-tree*.

You do your work—view and edit your files—with ordinary files that you can see and edit.  These are in your work-tree (also called *working tree* or any number of similar words and phrases; old version of Git also used the phrase *work directory* or *working directory*).  That's all pretty straightforward, because all your computer's tools and programs can deal with these files.

But Git doesn't make commits from the work-tree.  Git makes new commits from the *index*.  The index is so important (and/or so badly named) that it has three names in Git: Git sometimes calls it "the index" like this, but sometimes calls it the *staging area*, and occasionally—rarely these days—calls it the *cache*.  You're already familiar with the idea of using it to stage updated files; that's where the name *staging area* comes from.  But in fact, the index holds a copy<sup>3</sup> of *every* file that's going to go into your next commit.  This copy starts out the same as what's in the *current* commit, and as you update files and `git add` them, the index copy gets replaced with the updated file.

In other words, the index holds what you've proposed to make your *next* commit.  Running `git add` updates this proposed next commit.  To tell you what's *different* between your current commit and your proposed next commit, `git status` simply compares the files in the current commit to the files in the index.  When they're the same, it says nothing, and when they are different, it says "staged for commit".

So: when you run `git stash save` or `git stash push`, Git first makes a commit from the index, the same way it might make any commit from the index.  Then the stash code creates a temporary index—by copying the regular / real one—and `git add`s all the files from the work-tree into the temporary index, a la `git add -u`.  Then it makes a commit from this temporary index that matches your work-tree.

This is where the two commits come from.  All stashes have at least these two commits.  If you make a stash with the `-u` or `-a` flag, that adds a third commit ... which gets messy, so let's just assume you never do that.

When you *apply* or *pop* a stash—`pop` just means `apply` then `drop`—you choose at this time whether to use the first stash commit, with the index contents, or not.  If you use the `--index` flag, Git will attempt to apply the index commit to your current index.  This essentially runs a `git diff` operation piped to a `git apply --cached` (this is much easier to see in the old `git stash` shell script, which literally ran `git diff-tree --binary $s^2^..$s^2 | git apply --cached`).

If you *don't* use the `--index` option, `git stash apply` just *ignores* the stashed index!  It just goes on to do the remaining part of a `git stash apply`, which is to run `git merge-recursive`<sup>4</sup> directly on the three commits needed to merge the stashed work-tree with your current work-tree.  If this step succeeds, `git stash pop` will *drop* the stash, which makes it very difficult to recover the index.

I generally recommend avoiding `git stash` entirely,<sup>5</sup> but if you do use it, I recommend avoiding `git stash pop`.  It's easy to forget the `--index` flag.  If you used `git stash apply`, you still have the stash around and can reset (see footnote 4) and retry the apply with `--index`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `save` verb was the only one available until Git 2.13.  That version of Git added the `push` verb to allows for a bunch of additional options.

<sup>2</sup>There is a smaller unit of storage internally called a *blob*, but it's not suitable for stashes: you need a lot of blobs with names stored in Git's internal *tree* objects, and to gather them all together, you need a *commit* object, so that's why the commit is the essential storage-unit in Git.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, the index holds *references* to the internal *blob objects* mentioned in footnote 2.  These blob objects store file data in the compressed, read-only format that Git uses to keep files small and ready to be shared.  Since they're read-only, the copy of, say, `README.md` that's in dozens or hundreds of commits can be *shared* when it's the *same* copy.  The index can also share it.  Writing a new file into the index, with `git add`, really just compresses the file's contents into the blob format.  This automatically shares any existing copy of the file, or creates a new blob if needed.

<sup>4</sup>You should probably never run `git merge-recursive` yourself, as it bypasses the "is everything safely committed" check.  This check guarantees that if the merge goes badly, you can recover with a `git reset --hard`.  The `git stash` code bypasses this check and therefore can make it impossible to recover from an attempt to apply a stash.  It's therefore a good idea, if you use `git stash` at all, to make sure that `git status` says that everything is clean first.

<sup>5</sup>I still use it myself, but very rarely and only if I'm sure it is going to work.  Even then I can accidentally burn myself.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git stash pop --index` or `git stash apply --index` for your staged commits.